# Why the variance of uniformly distribution is like that?

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, variance

According to several reference,

The variance of uniformly distribution is like below:

$$\frac{1}{12} (b-a)^2$$

However, after calculating the variance from scratch:

$$\sum _{x=a}^b \frac{\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2}{b-a}$$

The result is this:

$$\frac{1}{12} (a-b-2) (a-b-1)$$

They are not the same.

Which is wrong?

Comment: You calculated it as discrete, but you quoted the continuous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X \sim \mathcal{U}(a,b)$ (where $\mathcal{U}$ denotes the **continuous** uniform distribution), then $f(x) = \mathbb{I}_{(a,b)}/(b-a)$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]
 = \int_a^b \frac{x\ dx}{b-a}
 = \frac{1}{b-a} \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}
 = \frac{b+a}{2},
$$
where the last step uses $b^2-a^2 = (b-a)(b+a)$.

Further,
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2]
 = \int_a^b \frac{x^2\ dx}{b-a}
 = \frac{1}{b-a} \frac{b^3-a^3}{3}
 = \frac{b^2+ab+a^2}{3},
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm{Var}\ X = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2
$$
Can you plug in and finish the arithmetic?